# Kibana date range not round down to nearest day

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I was working on the date range query in Kibana/elasticsearch and it gives weird results (My machine is running on EST/EDT timezone & kibana is installed on my machine). When I choose day as today in Kibana, I get the perfect time range (i.e. Starting today 00.00 - 23.59). Refer the pic below.

[image]

And when I give this following query on Visualization, it rounds the start time to GMT and end time to EST/EDT. All I needed is to round to EST midnight, not the UTC midnight. Pic below.

[image]

Any idea why it is happening so?
The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#time-units) says `/d - round down to the nearest day`, but why GMT?

Comment: Have you tried tweaking Kibana advanced settings `dateFormat:tz` to `EST` ?